# Introduced pagination into my react app. Works fine but getting some slowdown and unresponsive in-app navigation. Unmounted component warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-hooks

I introduced a new package to my react app called react-hooks-paginator (docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-paginator)) and added it to a few pages that I wanted to work with pagination (list of products for example). It works fine but after adding it it lead to a few unintended side effects.

1. It caused some slowdown when clicking around the pagination page numbers.
2. Some in-app navigation (using react-router-dom's "Links". Works similar to anchor tags, but keeps the session for logged in users) inside the pagination does not always work. Sometimes I have to click it multiple times.
3. Getting a: "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function." when I leave a page with pagination.

I'm almost certain the unmounted component warning is the root of the problem here, but I'm not sure how to deal with this error. Can someone explain what this warning means and what can solve it?

Below is one component I have with the pagination.

productListPublic.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Paginator from "react-hooks-paginator";
import { CardColumns, Card, Row, Col, ListGroup, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

function ProductListPublic(props) {
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const pageLimit = 9;
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [currentProducts, setCurrentProducts] = useState([]);

    const Product = props => (
        <Card>
            <Row>
                <Col md={{ span: 4 }}>
                    <Card.Title className="mt-4 text-center">
                        <Link to={`/products/list/${props.product._id}/`}>{props.product.name}</Link>
                    </Card.Title>
                </Col>
                <Col md={{ span: 8 }}>
                <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroup.Item className="text-truncate">{props.product.description}</ListGroup.Item>
                    {props.product.stock > 0 ? (
                        <ListGroup.Item>{props.product.stock} in stock</ListGroup.Item>
                    ) : (
                        <ListGroup.Item>Currently out of stock</ListGroup.Item>
                    )}
                </ListGroup>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Card>
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/products/")
        .then(res => {
            setProducts(res.data);
            setCurrentProducts(products.slice(offset, offset + pageLimit));
        }).catch(function(err) {
            setIsError(true);
        })
    }, [offset, products]);

    function productList() {
        if(searchTerm) {
            return products.filter(product => product.name.includes(searchTerm)).map((currentProduct, i) => {
                return <Product product={currentProduct} key={i} />;
            });
        } else {
            return currentProducts.map(function(products, i) {
                return <Product product={products} key={i} />;
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="text-center">
            <h2>Products List</h2>
            <Form>
                <Form.Row className="justify-content-sm-center">
                    <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6 }}>
                        <Form.Label htmlFor="formSearch">Search Products</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                                    controlid="formSearch"
                                    type="text"
                                    value={searchTerm}
                                    onChange={e => {
                                        setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    placeholder="Product Name (case sensitive)"
                                    />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
            </Form>
            <CardColumns>
                { productList() }
                {!searchTerm &&
                    <Paginator
                        totalRecords={products.length}
                        pageLimit={pageLimit}
                        pageNeighbours={2}
                        setOffset={setOffset}
                        currentPage={currentPage}
                        setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
                    />
                }
            </CardColumns>
            { isError &&<p>Something went wrong with getting the products!</p> }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductListPublic;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I find in your useEffect.

- Use a `isMount` variable to track the mount state of the element and be able to avoid updating the react state when it has already unmount. This should remove the Warning.

Final code:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        let isMount = true
        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/products/")
        .then(res => {
            if (!isMount) return // If element has unmount, dont update the state
            setProducts(res.data);
            setCurrentProducts(products.slice(offset, offset + pageLimit));
        }).catch(function(err) {
            if (!isMount) return // If element has unmount, dont update the state
            setIsError(true);
        })
        return () => {
          isMount = false
        }
    }, [offset, products]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but without product in the comparator, I don't get my list of products and I get this in the console: "./src/components/public-components/productListPublic.js
  Line 52:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'products'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setCurrentProducts' needs the current value of 'products'  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps".

Comment: Also the Links still don't work with one click, there must be some compatability problems between the react-hooks-paginator and react-router-dom packages

Comment: You are right about `products`, you can place in the hook comparator. Got confused by `products` and `currentProducts`. Not sure about the rest. I think you can create a minimal example in https://codesandbox.io/ and put all the information you can in a new question. Now that you have resolved the Warning, you can put focus in other possibilities.